# How to handle push notification when app is not running/app is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I am using firebase notification. When applicationState is background it's working fine. But when app is not running / terminated func getPushNotiData(_ notification: NSNotification) is not being call

Implementing NotificationCenter in appDelegate file to handle notification in dashView

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification 
userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: 
"getPushNotificationData"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}
```

And if app is not running / terminated Implementing NotificationCenter in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate method

```
 if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        let userInfo = launchOptions![.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any]
        if userInfo != nil {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "getPushNotificationData"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        }
    }
```

Handling NotificationCenter in dashView

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.getPushNotiData(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "getPushNotificationData"), object: nil)
}

@objc func getPushNotiData(_ notification: NSNotification){
    if let url = notification.userInfo!["url"] as? String {
        let destination = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationDlsViewController") as! NotificationDlsViewController
        destination.notiUrl = url
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
}
}
```

Comment: No method will be executed on Push Notification arrive when the application is not running/terminated/ in killed state. System will just show a Notification Popup.

Comment: check this post this will solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78119296/16577410

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app is not running (killed state) , you can't execute any methods or code , only if the user clicks the push notification you can receive object of it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` launchingOptions and handle it ....

Comment: @objc func getPushNotiData(_ notification: NSNotification) method is not executing when app is not running

Answer (score 0):

It's probabile that when you check `launchOptions` in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` your ViewController is not loaded yet so `viewDidAppear` has not been called and the ViewController is not registered in the Notification Center. Try to put some print statement and check the order of the calls when the app is launched from the notification.